# .html() help dont know how to handle it

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
...
success: function (reqCode) {
            if (reqCode['error_code'] == 1) {
                //Generiere Tabelle     
                $(".done").html( 
                    '<p class="bold center"><?php echo "Besucher ".$month_name[' + reqCode['month'] + ']." ".' + reqCode['year'] + '; ?></p>'
                    '<canvas id="cvs" width="680" height="250">[No canvas support]</canvas>'
                    '<script>'
                        'chart = new RGraph.Line("cvs", ' + reqCode['data_string'] + ');'
                        'chart.Set("chart.tooltips", ' + reqCode['labels_string'] + ');'
                        'chart.Set("chart.tooltips.effect", "expand");'
                        'chart.Set("chart.background.grid.autofit", true);'
                        'chart.Set("chart.gutter.left", 35);'
                        'chart.Set("chart.gutter.right", 5);' 
                        'chart.Set("chart.hmargin", 10);' +
                        'chart.Set("chart.tickmarks", "circle");'
                        'chart.Set("chart.labels", ' + $reqCode['labels_tooltip'] + ');'
                        'chart.Draw();'
                    '</script>'
                );      
                $('.done').fadeOut('slow'); 
                $('.done').fadeIn('slow');
            }   
}
```

I don't know why every new line needs its own '..'. Anyway it's not working. Looked into the API reference but found nothing useful :(

Edit: For my second question:

This is what JSON response:

```
$response['error_code'] = '1'; 
    $response['data_string'] = "[" . join(", ", $data) . "]";
    $response['labels_string'] = "['" . join("', '", $labels) . "']";
    $response['labels_tooltip'] = "['" . join("', '", $data) . "']";
    $response['month'] = $month_name[$month];
    $response['year'] = $year;

    echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: You need to `+` the strings together. But more important is that you cannot use `php` on the client...

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli: The php tag will be rendered before it will get to the client.

Comment: @Naor, if you notice he is trying to pass a value, returned from the ajax call, to the `php` script..

Comment: @Gaby aka G. Petrioli: You right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does seem to be something wrong with that `<script>` tag, but really?  You don't need to insert that `<script>` tag.  You're already running JavaScript; just do this:

```
success: function (reqCode) {
    if (reqCode['error_code'] == 1) {
        var month_name = <?php echo json_encode($month_name); ?>;
        //Generiere Tabelle     
        $(".done").html( 
            '<p class="bold center">Besucher ' + month_name[reqCode['month']] + ' ' + reqCode['year'] + '</p>'+
            '<canvas id="cvs" width="680" height="250">[No canvas support]</canvas>'
        );

        var chart = new RGraph.Line("cvs", reqCode['data_string']);
        chart.Set("chart.tooltips", reqCode['labels_string']);
        chart.Set("chart.tooltips.effect", "expand");
        chart.Set("chart.background.grid.autofit", true);
        chart.Set("chart.gutter.left", 35);
        chart.Set("chart.gutter.right", 5); 
        chart.Set("chart.hmargin", 10);
        chart.Set("chart.tickmarks", "circle");
        chart.Set("chart.labels", reqCode['labels_tooltip']);
        chart.Draw();

        $('.done').fadeOut('slow'); 
        $('.done').fadeIn('slow');
    }   
}
```

I've fixed some syntax errors in there, though I can't guarantee that there are none left.  Just watch the JavaScript console for errors.

Comment: As others have also mentioned in comments, that `$month_name` bit inside the `<?php` block won't work at all; you'll have to copy your entire `$month_name` array into a JavaScript array (i.e. `var month_name = <?php echo json_encode($month_name); ?>;`, and use the JavaScript array for JavaScript operations.  Heck, I may as well fix it in my answer.

Comment: yeah I just put the script tag into .html() cause .done is the container where the chart should be drawn.

Comment: Thanks this is the right answer :) It doesn't matter where I call the chart.Draw(); Fixed the php stuff too. Now I am only using json variables.

Comment: Me again. I need to convert reqCode['data_string'] reqCode['labels_string] and reqCode['labels_tooltips'] to Strings. Otherwise the diagram wont work. jQuery.parseJSON() is useful. But it only works for one of these three variables. Why?

Comment: Gonna need to know what's in your reqCode to answer that.  Just put `console.log(reqCode);` at the top of the function.  You might be able to figure out the problem yourself from what appears in your browser's JavaScript console.  If not... well, that kinda deserves another question.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a container element with class done on it, like:

```
<div class="done" />
```

In addition, you can short:

```
$('.done').html('..all the html..').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
```

Moreover, as Vivin Paliath said, you should concat all the strings in the html using +

```
'<a>'+
'asdsad'+
'</a>'
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You need + signs

```
success: function (reqCode) {
            if (reqCode['error_code'] == 1) {
                //Generiere Tabelle     
                $(".done").html('<p class="bold center"></p>'+
                    '<canvas id="cvs" width="680" height="250">[No canvas support]'+
                    '<script>'+
                        'chart = new RGraph.Line("cvs", ' + reqCode['data_string'] + ');'+
                        'chart.Set("chart.tooltips", ' + reqCode['labels_string'] + ');'+
                        'chart.Set("chart.tooltips.effect", "expand");'+
                        'chart.Set("chart.background.grid.autofit", true);'+
                        'chart.Set("chart.gutter.left", 35);'+
                        'chart.Set("chart.gutter.right", 5);' +
                        'chart.Set("chart.hmargin", 10);' +
                        'chart.Set("chart.tickmarks", "circle");'+
                        'chart.Set("chart.labels", ' + $reqCode['labels_tooltip'] + ');'+
                        'chart.Draw();'+
                    ''
                );      
                $('.done').fadeOut('slow'); 
                $('.done').fadeIn('slow');
            }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a **single** string to the `html()` function. Something like:

`$(".done").html("<p>hello</p><p>goodbye</p>")`.

If you need to combine multiple strings you will need to use string concatenation, like:

```
var combinedString = '<p>hello</p>' + '<p>goodbye</p>'
```